# AWS | Boto3 | RDS |function DownloadDBLogFilePortion |cannot download a log file because it contains binary data |

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, boto3, amazon-rds

When I try to download all log files  from a `RDS` instance, in some cases, I found this error in my python output:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the
>   DownloadDBLogFilePortion operation: This file contains binary data and
>   should be downloaded instead of viewed.

I manage correctly the pagination and the throttling (using The Marker parameter and the sleep function).

This is my calling:

`log_page=request_paginated(rds,DBInstanceIdentifier=id_rds,LogFileName=log,NumberOfLines=1000)`

## rds-> boto3 resource

And this is the definition of my function:

```
def request_paginated(rds,**kwargs):
     return rds.download_db_log_file_portion(**kwargs)
```

Like I said, most of time this function works but sometime it returns:

> "An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the
>   DownloadDBLogFilePortion operation: This file contains binary data and
>   should be downloaded instead of viewed"

Can you help me please? :)

UPDATE: the problem is a known issue with downloading log files that contain non printable sign. As soon as possible I will try the proposed solution provide by the aws support

LATEST UPDATE: This is an extract of my discussion with aws support team:

There is a known issue with non binary characters when using the boto based AWS cli, however this issue is not present when using the older Java based cli.

There is currently no way to fix the issue that you are experiencing while using the boto based AWS cli, the workaround is to make the API call from the Java based cli

the aws team are aware of this issue and are working on a way to resolve this, however the do not have an ETA for when this will be released.
So the solutions is: use the java API

Giuseppe

Comment: I'm sorry for the format :). this is my first post on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LATEST UPDATE: This is an extract of my discussion with aws support team:

There is a known issue with non binary characters when using the boto based AWS cli, however this issue is not present when using the older Java based cli.

There is currently no way to fix the issue that you are experiencing while using the boto based AWS cli, the workaround is to make the API call from the Java based cli

the aws team are aware of this issue and are working on a way to resolve this, however the do not have an ETA for when this will be released. So the solutions is: use the java API

Giuseppe

Comment: Tried with the java sdk and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html

> InvalidParameterValue : An invalid or out-of-range value was supplied
>   for the input parameter.

Invalid parameter in boto means the data pass does not complied. Probably an invalid name that you specified, possible something wrong with your variable id_rds, or maybe your LogFileName, etc.  You must complied with the function arguments requirement.

```
response = client.download_db_log_file_portion(
  DBInstanceIdentifier='string',
  LogFileName='string',
  Marker='string',
  NumberOfLines=123
)
```

(UPDATE)
For example, LogFileName must be te exact file name exist inside RDS instance.

For the logfile , please make sure the log file EXISTS inside the instance. Use this AWS CLI to get a quick check

```
aws rds describe-db-log-files --db-instance-identifier <my-rds-name>
```

Do check Marker (string) and NumberOfLines (Integer) as well.  Mismatch type or out of range. Skip them since they are not required, then test it later.

Comment: Hi, ok. I'm trying this solution.

Comment: Ok, @mootmoot I'm testing the your solution, isolating one of the log that I cannot downloaded. this is my new call:  <code>rds.download_db_log_file_portion(DBInstanceIdentifier="my-rds",LogFileName="slowquery/mysql-slowquery.log.23"). <code> Nothing to do. same error.  This is how I have defined my rds client: rds=boto3.client('rds',source_region,aws_access_key_id=DEFAULT_ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=DEFAULT_SECRET_KEY)

Comment: However in my last attempt I was trying to download directly the log which is present in "my-rds"

Comment: Can you check whether the log file exist inside  RDS,  use describe-db-log-files

Comment: Hi , Of course it is present :) (the name has been provided using the describe-db-log-files function). Moreover I try to download it using the aws-cli: same error.

Comment: Can it because of the log file has been rotated/removed. According to AWS, a large slow_query_log will be removed/rotated under particular conditions http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html

Comment: The log is present but if I View it by aws web console I see: "This file contains binary data and should be downloaded instead of viewed. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue"

Comment: Hi, If I try download slowquery/mysql-slowquery.log.22 it works.

Comment: Someone in AWS forum suggest specify "NumberOfLines" to get rid of the "file contains binary data"  error.

Comment: Well, no idea. since somebody suggest here.  Even there is question raise in boto3 github, no response.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=518941

Comment: hi, it's a known issue( I asked to aws support). Asap I will update with all information

Comment: I think that the problem is in the botocore library. I have the same issue with aws-cli and boto3. I try to download the log file using the aws cli I receive the same error